# How to display a post and its comments?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to view all posts, all comments for each post at once. While I have no problems with displaying posts, displaying comments is already a problem. One post can have multiple comments, so I have no idea how to create a query to display this. I tried to use LEFT JOIN but it didn't help. I include a table schema below the code to make my problem easier to understand.

```js
  <?php foreach ($tweet->userData as $user)
    { ?>

            <div class='col-xl-8' id='posty'>
                <div class='row' id='time'>
                    <div class='btn-block d-flex justify-content-between'>
                        <div class='imie'>
                           <?php  echo $user['autor']    ?>
                            </div>
                        <div class='czas'>
                           <?php echo $user['date_to_add'] ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php echo $user['comment'] ?>
                <form action='' method='post' id="myForm">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-12 col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-between' id='icon'>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_like' style="background-color: <?php if($user['like_color']==1){echo '#00FA9A';}else{echo 'black';} ?>" ><i class='fas fa-heart' ></i><input type='hidden' name='like' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>" /><span id="font"><?php echo $user['likes']?></span></button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_dislike' style="background-color: <?php if($user['dislike_color']==1){echo '#00FA9A';}else{echo 'black';} ?>"><i class='fas fa-heart-broken'></i><input type='hidden' name='dislike' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/><span id="font"><?php echo $user['dislikes']?></span></button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_comment' id="com" ><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i><input type='hidden' name='comment' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/><span id="font">Comment</span></button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_share' style="background-color: <?php if($user['share_color']==1){echo '#00FA9A';}else{echo 'black';} ?>" ><i class='far fa-share-square' ></i><input type='hidden' name='share' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/><span id="font"><?php echo $user['shares'] ?></span></button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="row d-flex">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 bg-success ">
                            <form method="post">
                                <textarea id="form103" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Co słychać?" name="komentarz"></textarea>
                                <div>
                                    <?php echo $aabbcc ?? '' ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger mt-2" name='dodaj_comment'><input type='hidden' name='com'  value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Publikuj</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

 <?php } ?>
```

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$session = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS author, post.comment, post.date_to_add, post_comment.comment, post_comment.date_to_add FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id  LEFT JOIN post_comment ON post.user_id=post_comment.post_id where post.user_id = :user_id order by post.id DESC");
$sql->bindParam(':user_id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':id',$session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();

    if($sql->rowCount())
    {
        $this->userData = [];

        while ($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
            $this->userData[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't use a second query and select all comments with that?

Comment: You have mistake in JOIN - you're joining post with post_comment on post.user.id = post_comment.post_id

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Comment form database for specific Post using `post_id` by selecting Comment Table:

`$query="select * form post_comment where post_id=". $post_id;`

here is the PHP Implementation :

```html
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql_post = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result = $conn->query($sql_post );

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> post id: ". $row["id"]. " - <br> Post: ". $row["post"]<br>";

$comment_query=$conn->query("select * form post_comment where post_id=". $row["id"]);

if ($comment_query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($comment= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo  " <p>Comment ".comment['comment']." </p>";
   }
}

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: This code is unsafe and should NOT be used!